# Waiting for variables to be defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, ejs

Im new on JS and im trying to make an API that make some requests to other websites , then render the data in a ejs template.

I hava some functions that make the request, but when I try to access to the result Im getting Variables undefined.

Here my code:

```
function callback_breakout(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // console.log(body);
        var data = JSON.parse(body)
        breakout_result = data.result
        console.log(breakout_result)
    }
}

function callback_vendor(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // console.log(body);
        var data = JSON.parse(body)
        vendor_result = data.result
        console.log(vendor_result)
    }
}

request(options_breakout, callback_breakout);
request(options_vendor, callback_vendor);

res.render('report',{
    breakout_result,
    vendor_result
})
```

Error:

```
(node:2224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: breakout_result is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First way is `setInterval`::**

```
var breakout_result = null;
var vendor_result = null;

function callback_breakout(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // console.log(body);
        var data = JSON.parse(body)
        breakout_result = data.result
        console.log(breakout_result)
    }
}

function callback_vendor(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // console.log(body);
        var data = JSON.parse(body)
        vendor_result = data.result
        console.log(vendor_result)
    }
}

request(options_breakout, callback_breakout);
request(options_vendor, callback_vendor);


var interval = setInterval(function() {
   if ( breakout_result !== null && vendor_result !== null ) {
       clearInterval(interval);
        
       res.render('report',{
          breakout_result,
          vendor_result
       });
   }
}, 500);
```

**Second way is use `callback`::**

```
var breakout_result = null;
var vendor_result = null;

function callback_breakout(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // console.log(body);
        var data = JSON.parse(body)
        breakout_result = data.result
        console.log(breakout_result)
    }
}

function callback_vendor(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // console.log(body);
        var data = JSON.parse(body)
        vendor_result = data.result
        console.log(vendor_result)
    }
}

// init request1
request(options_breakout, function() {
   callback_breakout(); // process request1

   // init request2
   request(options_vendor, function() {
        callback_vendor(); // process request2

        // now render content
        res.render('report',{
          breakout_result,
          vendor_result
       });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make breakout_result and vendor_result global.

like this:

```
var breakout_result, vendor_result;

    function callback_breakout(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            // console.log(body);
            var data = JSON.parse(body)
            breakout_result = data.result
            console.log(breakout_result)
        }
    }
    
    function callback_vendor(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            // console.log(body);
            var data = JSON.parse(body)
            vendor_result = data.result
            console.log(vendor_result)
        }
    }

request(options_breakout, callback_breakout);
request(options_vendor, callback_vendor);

res.render('report',{
    breakout_result,
    vendor_result
})
```

Comment: I have now edited the answer. Are you still getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Use var or let in front of breakout_result. but if you declare a variable inside a function
you can not use it outside the function
so if you need this variable in a different place something like

```
res.render('report',{
breakout_result,
vendor_result
})
```

you should declare the variable outside the function (global scope)
like that

```
var breakout_result;
var vendor_result;
function callback_breakout(error, response, body) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    // console.log(body);
    var data = JSON.parse(body)
        breakout_result = data.result
    console.log(breakout_result)
  }
}
function callback_vendor(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    // console.log(body);
    var data = JSON.parse(body)
        vendor_result = data.result
    console.log(vendor_result)
  }
}

    request(options_breakout, callback_breakout);
    request(options_vendor, callback_vendor);

    res.render('report',{
        breakout_result,
        vendor_result
    })
```